# Trying to convert NSTextField to string with NSDate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdate, nstextfield

```
-(void)updateString

    {
        NSString * timeStampString = @"1316641549";
        NSTimeInterval _interval=[timeStampString doubleValue];
        NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:_interval];
        NSLog(@"%@", date);

        [webView reload:0];
        [self.textField setStringValue:@"hi",date];
    }
```

Can someone quickly tell me what im doing wrong? I am trying to set my text field equal to my date but the `[self.textField setStringValue:@"hi",date];` is returning "Too many arguments" What does the formattting need to be? textField is a NSTextField.  Thanks!

Comment: `setStringValue:` expects a single argument, a string. `@"hi",date` is not just a string, it's a string and a date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *dateString = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:date 
                                                      dateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle 
                                                      timeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];

[self.textField setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"hi %@", dateString]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *Datestr = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:[NSDate date] dateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
```